# which elastic search node should I send rest calls to?

Tags: elasticsearch

if I want to edit my index settings for example I want to change the number of replicas then I would have to send a request with the number of replicas through rest end point. my question is which node should I send the request to ? to any node or specific node in the cluster ?

Comment: Any node is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can send a request to any node in the cluster, and the request will be appropriately routed to where it needs to be actioned

in this case, the request will be sent to the master node, the settings updated, and then a response sent back to the original node and onto the client